# How to generate a controller with a namespace that has 2 levels?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I generate a controller with mutiple levels of namespaces like:

```
/api/v1/users
```

This fails:

```
rails g controller api/v1/users
```

Error:

```
`namespace': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
rails g controller 'api/v1/users'
```

will generate the class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController in app/controllers/api/v1 directory.

Note this creates the controller in the Api::V1:: namespace, which is different than a controller defined thusly:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class Users
```

But you could always just change that manually after it's generated.

Comment: How are those different?  I thought it is the same thing when you use :: or if you have nested modules no?

Comment: It's different in the sense that it does not create a separate ::Api namespace that can be referenced independently the same way it does when you specify the modules separately.  In practice this might not matter.